# Main Menu and Catalog Tree View in ArcCatalog are not visible

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

In ArcCatalog (the program, not the window in ArcMap), the Main Menu (`File, Edit, View... Windows, Help`) at the top and the Catalog Tree View have disappeared and I can't find a way to reconnect them. How do I make them visible again?

Comment: How did you manage to remove the Main Menu?

Comment: For 10.1.. you have to go to Windows on the top menu -> then click Catalog

Answer (score 6):

Right-click anywhere in the gray area where menus or buttons would be at the top, or even on a button if you have any toolbars showing. Choose the Customize option, and in the resulting box you should be able to turn the Main Menu back on, from which as jbchurchill notes you can turn the Catalog Tree back on from the Windows dropdown menu.

If for some reason you don't have anywhere you can right-click to bring up that shortcut, the keyboard shortcut for it is alt-c though that may only work if you have the main menu visible (I can't turn mine off to test).

You might also want to check if things have been moved off-screen somehow. This is easiest to do by right-clicking somewhere on your desktop to get the display properties and changing the resolution, which will normally force any off-screen windows to redraw somewhere visible.

As a second-to-last resort, you can try deleting your Arc settings templates in your Windows user profile at:

- C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\normal.gxt
- C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates\normal.mxt

And as a very last resort... Reinstall Arc.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help... I had already tried all your suggestions... I must re-install Arc:-(

Comment: I've killed the normal.gxt and now it's ok.
Thank you very much for you help

Comment: I also had the same problem and deleting normal.gxt worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved by deleting the normal templates for ArcCatalog or ArcMap (depending on which one you are having problem, the files are located in:

- For ArcCatalog - `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\normal.gxt`
- For ArcMap - `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates\normal.mxt`

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. This appears to be a duplicate of @ChrisW 's answer--in particular the last paragraph: "As a second-to-last resort...". For the purposes of clarity, it is always best to upvote existing questions and possibly add a comment rather than posting duplicates. Alternatively, credit an existing answer and build on it as a new answer.